Tkinter askcolor function isn't changing the background colour of the frame
I am making an expense tracker as a fun project. I have encountered an issue where the colour choosing method I am using inside the frame class isn't working, could someone help please?
Here is my code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, colorchooser, messagebox


class ExpenseTracker(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Expense Tracker")
        self.geometry("700x700")
        self.minsize(700, 700)
        self.login = Login(self)
        self.mainloop()


class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        tk.Label(text="Enter Username:").place(relx=0.5, rely=0.36, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        tk.Label(text="Enter Password:").place(relx=0.5, rely=0.46, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        change_colour = tk.Button(text="Background Colour", command=self.change_colour)
        change_colour.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.1, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        username_entry = tk.Entry()
        username_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        password_entry = tk.Entry()
        password_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        login_box = tk.Button(text="Login")
        login_box.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.grid()

    def change_colour(self):
        color = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]
        self.configure(bg=color)


ExpenseTracker()

At first, the login class inherited from "ttk.Frame", which I wanted but I was getting an " unknown option "-bg"" error. Then, I changed it to inherit from "tk.Frame", which stopped the error from happening, but the background still doesn't change when I use the change colour button.

Note that all the widgets created inside Login frame are children of root window, not the frame itself, so the size of the frame will be 1x1 in pixels.  So you cannot see the frame. Even though you put all the widgets inside the frame, but since .place() is used on those widgets, the size of the frame will still be 1x1.

Thanks, in the login init class, I wrote self.config(width=700, height=700), and my code now works, the background colour is changing
